# Grails 3 Setup application.yml production mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-3.0

How to set the use connectionstring which usess mongodb in production.

```
development:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017/fanfest"

    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Working with Grails 3 version. Able to connect with mongodb in development environment. Kindly provide some suggestions to set the mongodb in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have development pointing at a mongo instance. The production configuration is pointed at the in memory H2 database. If you would like to configure a mongo database for your production environment may I suggest you take a look at [Getting Started](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html) guide for Mongo and GORM.

In the production section of your configuration file you can use the connection string parameter as follows:

```
production {    
    grails {
        mongodb {
            connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/PROD_fanfest"
        }
    }
}
```

Please note I have used your development URL but changed the table name since I recommend you keep the development database and production database separate. Configuring production datasource to use Mongo is that easy. There are more configuration options described in the [Getting Started](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html) documentation.

Relevant information on configuring options below:

```
options {
    connectionsPerHost = 10 // The maximum number of connections allowed per host
    threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 5
    maxWaitTime = 120000 // Max wait time of a blocking thread for a connection.
    connectTimeout = 0 // The connect timeout in milliseconds. 0 == infinite
    socketTimeout = 0 // The socket timeout. 0 == infinite
    socketKeepAlive = false // Whether or not to have socket keep alive turned on
    writeConcern = new com.mongodb.WriteConcern(0, 0, false) // Specifies the number of servers to wait for on the write operation, and exception raising behavior
    sslEnabled = false // Specifies if the driver should use an SSL connection to Mongo
    socketFactory = … // Specifies the SocketFactory to use for creating connections
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans!. There would be any database connection timed out

Comment: Please see the linked documentation on getting started in my answer.