# Completely lost on getting grails 3.X.X work with mongob

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have been struggling to get grails 3.1.7 to connect to local mongo db. I have implemented various suggestion via [main documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html). I have gone through some post on stackoverflow by [Alex M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707811/installing-and-using-mongodb-in-grails-3-x) and [Armarnath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796245/grails-3-setup-application-yml-production-mongodb)

My build.gradle looks like the following:

```
// ...
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb'
compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2"
runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE'
//compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver'
//compile("org.grails:gorm-mongodb-spring-boot:5.0.6.RELEASE")

//compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
//compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
// ...
```

My application.yml is looking like the snippet below:

```
//...
 environments:
  development:
    dataSource:
      grails:
        mongodb:
          connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017/project-db"
#        dbCreate: create-drop
#        url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
test:
    dataSource:
#        dbCreate: update
#        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
production:
    dataSource:
#        dbCreate: update
#         url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
#        properties:
#            jmxEnabled: true

//...
```

Here is a sample model:

```
class FlowInfo {

    int posIndex
    String tagName
    Boolean isEnabled
    String name
    static mapWith="mongo"
    static constraints = {
        posIndex unique: true
    }


}
```

It looks like I am still getting data pulled from the first initial in memory database created probably at the first run of the seeding from the BootStrap.groovy.  Is there a way to make this work. looks like different strategies worked  for different people.

thanks for reading this.

Comment: Did you try with `static mapWith = "mongo"` property in your domains?

Comment: sorry for the late revert. I did have mapWith

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with following configuration in application.yml that worked for me:

```
environments:
    development:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                connectionString: mongodb://localhost:27017/database-name
```

You might remove dataSource and try once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have upgraded to 3.1.7, and followed the latest documentation, commented out all datasource stuff but used application.groovy file rather.

Comment: can you upload example to reproduce on github?